# Is there a memory implementation of the SparseVectorsFromSequenceFiles, RowIdJob and RowSimilarityJob jobs

Tags: hadoop, mahout, semantic-analysis, lsa, latent-semantic-analysis

I've been working on performing Latent Semantic Analysis using the `SparseVectorsFromSequenceFiles`, `RowIdJob` and `RowSimilarityJob` Hadoop jobs provided by Mahout, which run Map/Reduce jobs. I've been trying to find an equivalent implementation for these functionality that runs in memory, either in a single thread, or preferably in multiple threads.

Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know, don't think so, but it would be trivial to write. You just open a `SequenceFile.Reader` and for each record, get the `Vector` from the value `Writable` and do what you want It's probably 10 lines of code and not worth a tool.